# Server error 500 in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

So today I have another small little issue with my PHP, that is causing me to get a server error. You see, I have this javascript function:

```
 $.post('script.php', { limit: str }, function(result) { 
  console.log(result); 
 });
```

which of course makes a call to my php file:

```
 require_once("../data/db-settings.php");
 require_once("../data/file.php");
 global $pdo;
 $list = array();
 $limit = $_POST["limit"];
 chop($limit, ";");
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cust_id, cust_addr FROM project  WHERE " . $limit . " = cust_id");
 $stmt->execute();
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $list[] = $row;
    }       
 echo $list;
```

The point of the php is to grab some information from a database that a user can dynamically change and use. The issue, I'm assuming, is with how I'm using PDO, because the code I'm using is in working order in another section. I also know that my function call is sending data and working properly, because when I check for just what I send, it sends properly.

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: Check your logs or enable debugging to see what the specific issue is

Comment: There should be a space between FROM and project in your SQL query.

Comment: Your code is susceptible for SQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an unobvious error!
So you step by step following the : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Answer (score 3):

Check your query `FROMproject` can not be together.

Your query should look like this:

```
$pdo->prepare("SELECT cust_id, cust_addr FROM project  WHERE " . $limit . " = cust_id");
```

Comment: The issue in the end was that my path was wrong, although I'm unsure of why, as the path was being used in the exact same place in another section. I resolved it by just moving the function over into the file

Answer (score 0):

PDO doesn't throw Internal server error. Must be require_once.

checkout db-settings.php and file.php files. Require_once throws 500 error if it can't find files.

If the paths are correct, then check out included files.

proper way: check your log files.

Comment: The issue in the end was that my path was wrong, although I'm unsure of why, as the path was being used in the exact same place in another section. I resolved it by just moving the function over into the file.